# Web Api route constraint tuples

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I have a route like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{tenantParam1}/{tenantParam2}/{controller}/{id},
    constraints: ???,
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

For tenantParam1, and tenantParam2, I need to constrain them so that only certain tuples of values are allowed. Is there a way to do that?

Edit: to clarify, the important part is that I need to evaluate tenantParam1 and tenantParam2 together, as a tuple. For instance, lets say these are my valid tenants:

```
param1 | param2
ABC    | 123
ABC    | 456
DEF    | 789
DEF    | 012
```

That would mean the following routes are valid:

```
/api/ABC/123
/api/ABC/456
/api/DEF/789
/api/DEF/012
```

But the following routes are not valid:

```
/api/ABC/789
/api/ABC/012
/api/DEF/123
/api/DEF/456
```

Comment: Link-only answers are not liked, but I will not paste the entire post here, so just read this: https://chsakell.com/2013/10/13/web-api-custom-routing-constraints/

Comment: Thanks, but this only seems to cover custom constraints for a single parameter. I need to constrain two parameters together as a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example yuo have to tweek it according to your need. Create constraint class

```
public class SomeConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, 
        IDictionary<string, object> values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        //get value from values dictionary object
        //return true or false 
        //false will block the call
     }
}
```

Then register it in config file

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
        constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("someConstraint", typeof(SomeConstraint ));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
    }
```

and use it as below

```
[Route("{value:someConstraint}")]
```

Comment: This only allows me to constrain one parameter at a time. I need a constraint that will allow me to evaluate tenantParam1 and tenantParam2 together

Comment: Looks like this can still be used, since all the route values are passed into the `Match` method. It just needs to be registered like this: `constraints: new { tenantParam1 = new TenantConstraint() }`

Comment: exactly u can pass in multiple parameters it all depends how u set and decorate ur route